# Get translation text without using FormattedMessage and React ContextTypes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-intl

I'm looking for a way to get translation text without using FormattedMessage. Until now, I've found only this solution that provides to use [ContextTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186297/how-to-retrieve-a-string-in-reactintl-2-0-without-using-formattedmessage)   an [React's EXPERIMENTAL feature](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). Are there others ways to accomplish this (or other library/npm module)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using `context`, but react-intl does also provide a higher order component [`injectIntl`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#injectintl) you can use instead. This will pass a prop `intl` that has all the imperative formatting functions.

```
import React from "react";
import {injectIntl, intlShape} from "react-intl";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        intl: intlShape.isRequired
    }
    render() {
        return <p>{this.props.intl.formatDate(new Date())}</p>;
    }
}

export default injectIntl(Component);
```

Comment: I would prefer using context's solution, but it is an experimental feature that could change at any time. Do you know other library like react-intl?

Comment: @Webman I'm not sure you understood my answer, I updated it to clarify: you can use react-intl's `injectIntl` function *instead* of `context`. This is provided by react-intl.